# details on the following Natural Language Processing terms?

Tags: nlp, libraries, text-processing

```
Named Entity Extraction (extract ppl, cities, organizations)
Content Tagging (extract topic tags by scanning doc)
Structured Data Extraction
Topic Categorization (taxonomy classification by scanning doc....bayesian )
Text extraction (HTML page cleaning)
```

are there libraries that i can use to do any of the above functions of NLP ?

dont really feel like forking out cash to AlchemyAPI

Comment: Maybe it would help if you described what you wanted to use the Alchemy API to accomplish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are actually plenty of freely available open-source natural language processing packages out there. Here's a brief list, organized by what language the toolkit is implemented in:

- **Python**: [Natural Language Toolkit NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)
- **Java**: [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/), [Gate](http://gate.ac.uk/), and [Stanford's JavaNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/)
- **.NET**: [Sharp NLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/Wikipage)

If you're uncertain which one to go with, I would recommend starting with  [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/). The package is reasonably easy to use and has great documentation online, including [a free book](http://www.nltk.org/book).

You should be able to use NLTK to easily accomplish the NLP tasks you've listed, e.g. [named entity recognition (NER)](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html#named-entity-recognition), [extracting tags for documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661778/tag-generation-from-a-text-content), and [document categorization](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch06.html#document-classification).

What the Alchemy people call [structured data extraction](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/scrape/) looks like it's just HTML scrapping that is robust against changes to the underlying HTML as long as the page still visually renders the same way. So, it's not really a NLP task.

For the extraction of text from HTML, just use [boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/). It's fast, good, and free.

Comment: omg this is the answer i was looking for ! YOU SIR ARE AWESOME

Comment: If the task at hand is boilerpipe, there's no need to finish an argument about training data.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) project was originally created by IBM and provides an NLP framework much like GATE.  There are various annotators out there that are built for UIMA.