# How to extract keywords (tags) from text

Tags: tags, nlp, keyword, nltk

i am currently trying to implement a tagging engine in Java and searched for solutions to extract keywords/tag from texts (articles). I have found some solutions on stackoverflow suggesting to use Pointwise Mutual Information.

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764116/tag-generation-from-a-small-text-content-such-as-tweets)

[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661778/tag-generation-from-a-text-content/2664351#2664351)

I cant use pyton and nltk so i have to implement it myself. But i dont know how to calculate the probabilities.
The equation looks like this:

```
PMI(term, doc) = log [ P(term, doc) / (P(term)*P(doc)) ]
```

What i want to know is how to calculate P(term, doc)

I already have a lange text corpus and a collection of articles. The articles are not part of the corpus. The corpus is indexed with lucene.

Please help me out.
Best regards.

Comment: Do you want to extract the tags or calculate the probabilities? Your title suggests extract tags, but your question says you don't know how to calculate the probabilities - why do you care about probabilities?

Comment: i want to extract tags and therefore i have to calculate P(term, doc) but i dont know how to do it

Comment: Why do you have to calculate anything? Please define "extract tags" too.

Comment: I have a text and want to extract/generate single word tags from the given text content. PMI seems to be a good solution but i dont know how to implement it properly because i dont know how to calculate P(term, doc)

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of algorithms for doing this:

**open source tools:**

kea(http://www.nzdl.org/Kea/) supervised approach uses training data and controlled vocabulary

maui indexer(http://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/) it is basically extension of kea which provide facility to use encyclopedia for key phrase extraction.

carrot2(http://project.carrot2.org/) unsupervised approach for key phrase extraction. it supports lot of variation of input, output format and parameters for key phrase extraction.

mallet topic modeling module(http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php)

Stanford topic modeling tool (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/)

Mahout clustering algorithms(http://mahout.apache.org/)

**Commercial api:**

zemanta API(http://www.zemanta.com/developer/)

yahoo term extraction api(http://developer.yahoo.com/contentanalysis/)

Comment: this answer is copied from
https://www.quora.com/What-are-good-tools-to-extract-key-words-and-or-topics-tags-from-a-random-paragraph-of-text/answer/Vineet-Yadav?srid=kKqE