# How to find the headings from a given paragraph in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create some functionality that can give me title of the given chat conversation or paragraph.
Title here is like - "What the chat is all about" or what the paragraph is all about.

I have tried StanfordCoreNLP to achieve sentence tokenization and sentence recognizer. But my main aim is to search for some keywords from the paragraph or input text and to determine what is the actual title or heading of the input text is.

I have tried this -

```
public class Pipeline {
    private static Properties properties;
    private static String propertiesName = "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, sentiment, ner";
    private  static StanfordCoreNLP stanfordCoreNLP;

    private Pipeline(){
    }
    static {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("annotators", propertiesName);
    }
    public static StanfordCoreNLP getPipeline(){
        if(stanfordCoreNLP == null){
            stanfordCoreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
        }
        return stanfordCoreNLP;
    } }
```

SentenceRecognizer.java -

```
public class SentenceRecognizer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      StanfordCoreNLP stanfordCoreNLP= Pipeline.getPipeline();

      String text = "Hey Iam Jhon. Iam doing Math. I like coffee ";
        CoreDocument coreDocument = new CoreDocument(text);
        stanfordCoreNLP.annotate(coreDocument);
       List<CoreSentence> sentences= coreDocument.sentences();
       for(CoreSentence sentence: sentences){
           System.out.println(sentence.toString());
       }
    }
}
```

Output -

```
Hey Iam Jhon.
Iam doing Math.
I like coffee
```

Similarly I have implemented Tokenization, Part of Speech, Sentiment Analysis and Lemma.

The Output I want -
Example Paragraph as **Input** -

> If you could make a holiday, what would it be like? What traditions
> would it have? What would people eat on your holiday?

Expected **Output** - *Holiday*

Anyone can help me with the logic, to generate the title out of this String using all these. Please Help

Comment: You’re going to need to be more specific on what ‘title | heading’ means to you. But I doubt there’s a specific library for this - although almost certainly libraries you can leverage to achieve the goal.

Comment: @BeUndead I have edited my question and tried to be more descriptive. please help me with this

Comment: Can you give examples of what you would like the output to be for various inputs?

Comment: @tgdavies ok I have added one example I hope it's ok, what I actually want is to somehow identify the topic of conversation between two people, you can think of it like a  chatbot which can keep track of conversation between two people and tell us what that conversation is all about whether it was a business related discussion or sports  related :|

Comment: In which case does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25426203/2478398