# Single KeyWord Extraction from A Document

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I wish to generate keywords from small text such as user tweets. I have already checked out these links.
[tag generation from a small text content (such as tweets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764116/tag-generation-from-a-small-text-content-such-as-tweets) 
[tag generation from a text content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661778/tag-generation-from-a-text-content/)

The problem is they use bigram or trigram collocations, hence they find only multi-word key phrases. I wish to find a single keyword as the topic. How should I modify them ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this thread:
[Sorted Word frequency count using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088265/word-frequency-count-using-python)

It lists multiple approaches, so pick one that's easiest for you.