# Gensim HDP - Top Topics' distribution for document

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I want topic distribution for my documents. However, Gensim's HDP's `show_topic()` **returns 20 topics by default**. And I suppose they are not supposed to be the best. After digging deeper, I found out there are total 150 topics, as the truncation level in the code is set to 150 by default [code](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/_modules/gensim/models/hdpmodel.html).

I came across another post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543542/hierarchical-dirichlet-process-gensim-topic-number-independent-of-corpus-size), which offers ways to select optimum number of topics. But, even if we identify top topics, **how do we represent new documents in terms of identified topics**? Because `hdp[doc]` again gives the distribution amongst 150 topics.

HDP is supposed to select optimum number of topics itself unlike LDA where we decide the number of topics. However, I am not able to achieve it in Gensim's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is no method to return a matrix of shape documents x topics. There is however a way to construct such a matrix. You execute:

```
<gensim.models.hdpmodel.HdpModel>.inference(chunk=single_document)
```

for each document in the corpus.