# How does Yelp create the "Review Highlights" section?

Tags: web-services, algorithm, search, text, yelp

Take the following link as an example: http://www.yelp.com/biz/chef-yu-new-york.

In the section called 'Review Highlights', there are 3 phrases (spicy diced chicken, happy hour, lunch specials) that are highlighted based on reviews submitted by users. Obviously, these are the phrases that appeared most often, or longest phrases that appeared often, or some other logic.

Their official explanation is this:

> In their reviews, Yelpers mentioned the linked phrases below a lot.
>   And these aren't any old common phrases, they're also the ones that
>   our Yelp Robots have determined are unique and good, quick ways to
>   describe this business. Click any of the phrases to see all the
>   reviews that mention it.

My question is, what did they use to mine the text input to get these data points? Is it some algorithm based on Lempel Ziv, or some kind of map reduce? I was not a CS major, so probably am missing something foundational here. Would love some help, theories, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any insight on the exact algorithm Yelp is using but this is a common problem in natural language processing. Essentially you want to extract the most relevant **collocations** (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation).

A simple way to do this is to extract a list of **n-grams** with the highest PMI (pointwise mutual information). This SO question explains how to do this using Python and the nltk library:

[How to extract common / significant phrases from a series of text entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452982/how-to-extract-common-significant-phrases-from-a-series-of-text-entries)

Answer (score 0):

Lempel-Ziv is a data compression algorithm, and map-reduce is a technique for data processing. The former is probably not involved, and the latter is generally useful but not relevant here.

Without knowing the details of Yelp's code, it's impossible to say for sure, but it seems *likely* that their "review highlights" are simply based on tabulating all phrases that appear in reviews for this business, then displaying ones which are more common in reviews for this business than for other businesses. Some amount of natural language processing is likely to be involved to ensure that it picks noun phrases.

Comment: It's that "tabulating all phrases" that is interesting to me. I thought that since the phrases are of varying length and complexity, perhaps they were using some variation of LZ to create a dictionary and then output the 3 longest or most used phrases. Perhaps they achieve it some other way. Any ideas on what they could be using? Tool, technology or algorithm-wise?