# How to get task title using python

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp

I am making a project in NLP. But found a problem. I saw that google assistant or **cortana** has a feature where you tell them them to remind you for a work. For example:
You tell Cortana "*Remind me to water the plants tomorrow at 6PM*". Then **cortana** creates a work named "*Water the plants*".

This is the thing I am trying to understand :

[image]

Then sets the time, date etc. But how does it find the title "*Water the plants*". Is there any way where I can extract the title of given task using NLP in python? Please help me if you anything about this or what is called.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably quite a few ways to tackle this:

1. I suppose your problem could generally fall under the *[span identification](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.02587)* umbrella. A classic approach, used in NER for example, would be to do token-level labeling of the titles within each text and train a model to predict those labels.
2. You could also use chunking to get verb or noun 'chunks', which may suffice as titles. [Here](https://streamhacker.com/2009/02/23/chunk-extraction-with-nltk/) is an article on noun chunking with NLTK and [here](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html#fig-chunk-segmentation) is NLTK's own chapter on chunking (shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642400/8758205) to another question).
3. You could also use a rule-based system if the language used is
   fairly predictable. For example, you can hand-craft custom regexes
   to capture the essential parts of the task (e.g. everything after
   phrases *like* 'remind me to' and excluding temporal expressions *like*
   'tomorrow at 6pm'). This is a limited and less flexible approach but
   can work well in certain cases.
4. Another approach would be to create a dataset of full texts paired with their 'titles', and train a language model (maybe even
   QA-style?) to predict these titles from texts. [Here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/extract-the-right-phrase-from-sentence-29aa5f8b9182) is a blog
   post about someone working on a task involving extraction of a phrase from a larger text, which is quite different but may still have relevant sections.
5. It could also be worth looking into text summarization (e.g. [with huggingface](https://huggingface.co/transformers/usage.html#summarization)), although I'm not sure how well that would work on mostly short texts like these and how useful the outputs would be.

There are likely more options out there too, but these are the first that come to mind.